# Find all subsets with given average

Tags: c#, subset-sum

Given a set of numbers :{1, 4, 5, 3, 2} and average = 2.5, find all subsets with average 2.5. e.g here answer will be {1,4},{1,4,3,2},{3,2}

I want to solve this close to polynomial time in C#

Comment: This appears to be homework. What approaches have you tried thus far? You might consider mentioning what you have done (and why it isn't working) and then folks might be more apt to help fill in the gaps along the way.

Comment: Hint: related to the *subset sum* problem.

Comment: Not an assignment, it's a part of personal project. Following is the code I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Not an assignment, it's a part of personal project. Following is the code I tried.

Here a = average, w = {1,2,3,4,5} and m = target average.

```
public void SumOfSubset(double a, int k)
        {
            if (k > 4) return;
            x[k] = 1;
            var count = x.Where(i => i == 1).Count();
            if (((a * (count - 1)) + w[k]) / count == m)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++)
                {
                    if (x[i] == 1)
                    {
                        Console.Write(w[i] + ",");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }


                if (((a * (count - 1)) + w[k] + w[k + 1]) / (count + 1) <= m)
                {
                    SumOfSubset(((a * (count - 1)) + w[k]) / count, k + 1);
                }
                if (((a * (count - 1)) + w[k + 1]) / count <= m)
                {
                    x[k] = 0;
                    SumOfSubset(a, k + 1);
                }


        }
```